# Pointer of arma::mat or arma::vet as arguments of Rcpp function for internal purpose only

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am developing an R package using RcppArmadillo. I was writing a few util functions, which manipulate arma::mat and arma::vec objects. So I was trying to use pointer of arma::mat (or arma::vec) as arguments of those functions. Just like the following C++ example (https://onlinegdb.com/mNczwaPaV), I just want to pass the address of object, then manipulate the object value:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void plus_one(int *x){
    *x = *x + 1;
}
int main(){
    int x = 1;
    plus_one(&x);
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

```
2

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Here is a toy example I was trying. RStudio gave me the error message "called object type 'arma::vec *' (aka 'Col *') is not a function or function pointer."

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

void f2(arma::vec *v){
  *v = (*v)%log(*v) + (1-(*v))*log(1-(*v));
}

void trim(arma::vec *v, double tol){
  *v(find(*v<=0.0)).fill(tol);
  *v(find(*v>=1.0)).fill(1-tol);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec f1(arma::vec v){
  trim(&v, 1e-8);
  return(f2(&v));
}

/*** R
f1(seq(0,1,0.2))
*/
```

I don't think v.memptr() allows me to manipulate the vector by R-like vector operations. For example,

```
double* v_mem = v.memptr();

*v_mem+1;
```

does not give the entrywise addition result. (Here, I want is v+1 in R). Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: "So I was trying to use pointer of arma::mat (or arma::vec) as arguments of those functions. "  Why?  We use `const &` which are as fast.  Moreover, you failed to notice that you need to adhere to a) the specific R interface `SEXP .Call(SEXP ...)` if you want to it by hand or b) the specific available template conversion in our package,  And because your pointer does not make sense, there is none.

Comment: Also welcome to StackOverflow.  There are almost 3000 questions to Rcpp here, many of which are for RcppArmadillo. Checking some out,  or looking at the Rcpp Gallery, or looking through the package and its included benchmarks (!!) may be of interest to you,

Comment: Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel! I just need to review Rcpp and RcppArmadillo examples... Didn't know about `const &`. So just like [your Kalman filter example in your document on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/vignettes/RcppArmadillo-intro.pdf), `mat estimate(const mat & Z)` would work well, right?